# Kafka commit strategy for Asynchronous processing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use case to process messages asynchronously with throttling.

Lets say, I have a ThreadPoolExecutor with 10 threads and the operation being done by each thread may take upto 5 mins. So, after calling consumer.poll(), i am getting 10 messages and sending the same to ThreadPoolExecutor to process asynchronously. I should not poll for more messages before threads are available in the ThreadPoolExecutor. If i go for auto commit, the offset will be committed but the processing is not done yet and might lose messages if the system crash in between. If I go for a manual commit, I may need to wait until all 10 messages are processed and one of the message might take long time to complete and may need to wait until all 10 gets processed. So, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Sounds like you tried to recreate this? https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer